# Monitor no longer working after upgrading graphics card

Tags: xorg, nvidia, graphics, lightdm

I have recently upgraded my graphics card from a GTX 760 to a GTX 1070. When I started up Linux, I got an error in lightdm. I assumed this was standard and I just needed to install the new drivers, so I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and ran `# apt-get upgrade nvidia*`. This command got stuck several times over, and I needed to prod it along with ^C. Needless to say, this didn't solve the problem.

I tried a few other solutions, including commenting out the "Nvidia" block in the Xorg.conf file:

```
# -xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 340.46  (buildd@brahms)  Tue Oct  7 08:00:32 UTC 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device" #I commented out from here
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection #to here

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
```

I was hoping that this would make Xorg stop trying to use the Nvidia drivers and instead use the ones already in the kernel. Instead, when I ran `service lightdm start`, my monitor went black and gave the message "Not supported".

I cannot seem to get out of this: I tried stopping the lightdm service, restarting the computer, running `Xorg :1 -configure`, reinstalling the nvidia drivers, and reinstalling my DE.

I currently am connected to my computer via SSH, so I cannot do anything that would require changing the network settings.

Here are some other logs that may or may not be useful:

```
# lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f0 (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

# service lightdm status
● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2017-01-12 20:48:12 EST; 24min ago
     Docs: man:lightdm(1)
 Main PID: 11896 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 12 20:48:12 homebox systemd[1]: lightdm.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 12 20:48:12 homebox systemd[1]: Unit lightdm.service entered failed state.
Jan 12 20:48:12 homebox systemd[1]: lightdm.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 12 20:48:12 homebox systemd[1]: Stopping Light Display Manager...
Jan 12 20:48:12 homebox systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Jan 12 20:48:12 homebox systemd[1]: lightdm.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Jan 12 20:48:12 homebox systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager.
Jan 12 20:48:12 homebox systemd[1]: Unit lightdm.service entered failed state.

# Xorg

X.Org X Server 1.16.4
Release Date: 2014-12-20
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux homebox 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=572d5efa-5f06-4960-a090-810a2baf440b ro initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet
Build Date: 11 February 2015  12:32:02AM
xorg-server 2:1.16.4-1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Jan 12 21:13:15 2017
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

# cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[  2268.438] 
X.Org X Server 1.16.4
Release Date: 2014-12-20
[  2268.438] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  2268.438] Build Operating System: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[  2268.438] Current Operating System: Linux homebox 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64
[  2268.438] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=572d5efa-5f06-4960-a090-810a2baf440b ro initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet
[  2268.438] Build Date: 11 February 2015  12:32:02AM
[  2268.438] xorg-server 2:1.16.4-1 (http://www.debian.org/support) 
[  2268.438] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[  2268.438]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  2268.438] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  2268.438] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Jan 12 21:13:15 2017
[  2268.439] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[  2268.439] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  2268.439] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[  2268.439] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[  2268.439] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[  2268.439] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[  2268.439] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[  2268.439] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[  2268.440] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  2268.440] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  2268.440] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  2268.440] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  2268.440]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2268.440] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[  2268.440] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  2268.440] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[  2268.440] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[  2268.440] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[  2268.440] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f00cc8b7d80
[  2268.440] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  2268.440]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  2268.440]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[  2268.440]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[  2268.440]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[  2268.441] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:1b81:3842:6171 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf6000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[  2268.441] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  2268.441] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[  2268.454] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  2268.454]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  2268.454]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[  2268.454] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  340.96  Sun Nov  8 22:06:18 PST 2015
[  2268.454] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  2268.454] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[  2268.455] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  2268.455]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  2268.455]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2268.455] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  340.96  Sun Nov  8 21:46:28 PST 2015
[  2268.455] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[  2268.455] (--) using VT number 3

[  2268.465] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  2268.465] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  2268.465] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[  2268.465] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2268.465]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  2268.465]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  2268.465] (WW) Unresolved symbol: fbGetGCPrivateKey
[  2268.465] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[  2268.465] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[  2268.465] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[  2268.465] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2268.465]    compiled for 1.16.4, module version = 1.0.0
[  2268.465]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  2268.465] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[  2268.465] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[  2268.465] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[  2268.468] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[  2268.468] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[  2268.468] (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
[  2268.468] (EE) No devices detected.
[  2268.468] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  2268.468] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[  2268.468] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  2268.468] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  2268.468] (EE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that I had installed the wrong driver because I was stuck on the stable repository of debian.

By adding backports I was able to get the correct version.

A restart then booted up the Xserver correctly.

Commands in case anyone else has this problem:

```
cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
echo "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -t jessie-backports nvidia-driver
shutdown -r 00
```